# How to install binary Debian packages from github assets into the ReadTheDocs build environment?

Tags: python, read-the-docs

I have a python library that relies on a C library back-end that I'm trying to get into ReadTheDocs.  There are Debian packages for the C library available in another git project.

I wrote the following script to fetch the latest version of the packages and install them:

```
#!/bin/sh
list=`
    curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/scott-guthridge/libvna/releases/latest" |
        grep "browser_download_url" | cut -d '"' -f 4 |
    while read x; do
        case "$x" in
        *.deb)
            curl -L -O "$x"
            base=\`basename "$x"\`
            echo -n " ./$base"
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
        esac
    done`
echo "list: $list"
exec sudo apt install -y $list
```

I use this same script in the CI/CD process of yet another github project that relies on the same C library.

My .readthedocs.yaml script is:

```
version: 2
build:
  os: ubuntu-22.04
  tools:
    python: "3.11"
  apt_packages:
    - sudo
  jobs:
    pre_create_environment:
      - .github/scripts/install-libvna.sh

sphinx:
  configuration: docs/source/conf.py
```

where install-libvna.sh is the script above.  In the ReadTheDocs build, the script runs and successfully fetches the Debian packages from github assets, but it then fails in the "sudo" command.  Initially, sudo complained that there was no tty.  I added the -S option to tell it to read the password from stdin (which is just EOF in this case) -- now it complains no password was given.  I also tried removing the sudo and just running the "apt" command directly -- that complained that it wasn't running as root.

Debian packages can be installed through the apt_packages tag, but the packages for this library aren't (currently) available in any Linux distro.  How can I get my prerequisite packages installed?

Comment: How do you propose to be able to type in the `sudo` password from your CI/CD? Or is that what you are trying to ask? Probably the simplest fix is to publish a PPA with your packages which can then easily be added to your Apt sources.

Comment: I'm assuming the password is empty as it is in the github CI/CD process.  Do you know if the .readthedocs.yaml spec provides a way to specify alternate Apt sources?

Comment: Then just `sudo -S command <<<""` (if you use `/bin/bash`) or `printf "\n" | sudo -S command`

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't clear.  My script works fine as is in the github CI/CD process -- if you want to run a command as root there, you just say sudo command without any password and it works.  But this approach doesn't work in the ReadTheDocs container build process. Either root has a password there (unclear if it's published) or doesn't accept any password.  I don't necessarily really need to run any command as root -- I'm just looking for a way to install outside of distro Debian packages in the ReadTheDocs build environment.

Comment: Edit: I know with sudo, it's not root's password that matters, but rather the build user account.  Just substitute build user for root above.  Another possibility, though, is that the build user isn't a permitted sudoer.  I didn't try `su -c command`.

Comment: Many CI/CD systems disallow `sudo` for what should be obvious reasons. Probably use their Apt system instead, whatever it's like. I'm not familiar with this particular platform, unfortunately.

Comment: As an aside, the humongous variable is pretty fugly. `curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/scott-guthridge/libvna/releases/latest" | grep "browser_download_url" | cut -d '"' -f 4 | grep '\.deb$' | xargs -n1 basename` should produce a list of file names (maybe also replace the `grep | cut` with `jq -r '.assets[] | .browser_download_url'`) which you can then pass to `curl` and `apt`; probably also prefer modern `$(command substitution)` syntax over legacy backticks.

Comment: Could someone please answer the question I asked? Is it possible to install Debian packages from github assets, or alternatively, a C library from source, in the specific container build environment used by ReadTheDocs?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that installing out of distro binary packages cannot currently be done in the ReadTheDocs build environment.  First, the [build.apt_packages section](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#build-apt-packages) says that Personal Package Archives (PPA's) and other custom repositories are not supported. Next, the [build.os section](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#build-os) shows that the choice of build container is limited to two different versions of Ubuntu -- so creating a custom container with the library preinstalled also doesn't work.  And as I already tried above, the custom build options, e.g. pre_system_environment and pre_create_environment, run with user permission (user "docs") that don't allow apt/dpkg commands to install.

I was able to get the library into the build a different way, though:

- In the post_system_dependencies, git clone the source for the library, build, and install into $HOME/.local
- In the [ReadTheDocs GUI](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/environment-variables.html), add an environment variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/docs/.local/lib
- Modify the package's build script to look for headers and libraries in ~/.local as well as the standard locations in the Cython build step.
- In the post_install step, `pip install .` to build the library.

With this, automodule is finally able to access the doc strings from the code.  Working example is [here](https://github.com/scott-guthridge/pylibvna).